# RCurl equivalent to this...

Tags: r, rcurl

I am currently using this R code to get what I want to do done on an Ubuntu machine...

```
jsontext <- '{"text": "its really cold in here"}'
a <- paste('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ', " '", jsontext, "'", ' -X POST http://urlhere', sep="")
response <- system(a)
```

This gives me what I would get when entering this in a command prompt...

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"text": "its really cold in here"}' -X POST http://urlhere
```

I've tried using RCurl postForm(uri="http://urlhere", with various options...)  and haven't had any results.  Is it faster to do it this way or worth figuring it out?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you got an error message or something, which is really some result. If not, you may want to have a look at the `basicHeaderGatherer` and inspect the HTTP headers.